# Undefined is not an object(evaluating) - angular

Tags: angular

I am passing data a from one component to another component in my application but i keep getting the error. I am trying to pass the object types from this.loggedInGames to advanced of play_game which is binding to an input in my html.

**error**

> `undefined is not object(evaluating this.loggedInGames.types)`.

Below is my code

**component**

```
 constructor(){
     this.play_game.advanced = this.loggedInGames.types
     this.loggedInGames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInGames'));
 }

 play_game = {
    advanced : "",
    amateur : ""                
 }
```

**html**

```
<input name="amateur" [(ngModel)]="play_game.advanced" />
```

Comment: You are reading `this.loggedInGames.types` before you initialize it with `this.loggedInGames = JSON.parse(...)`

Comment: Properly formatting your code increases chances to get an answer a lot ;-)

Comment: @amateur mark as answer if it has  helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order should be changed, You are trying to access from a not initialized object.

```
 this.loggedInGames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedInGames'));
 this.play_game.advanced = this.loggedInGames.types;
```